# Old-style plist error when starting groovysh

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Whenever I start groovysh, I get this:

```
➜  ~  groovysh
2016-01-01 18:47:06.192 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.193 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.194 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.194 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.194 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.194 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.195 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
2016-01-01 18:47:06.195 java[96756:2338366] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 7. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.
Groovy Shell (2.4.5, JVM: 1.8.0_65)
```

It doesn't seem to affect performance, but if it's something that has a simple solution, I'd like to fix it.

I'm on OSX El Capitan 10.11.1

Thanks

Comment: keyboard-layout issue? maybe https://github.com/Lutzifer/keyboardSwitcher/issues/1 might be relevant?

Comment: @NathanHughes Maybe. Thanks for pointing it out.  I hadn't even considered that as a possible cause.